# installing rbenv on mac failure

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems, rbenv

I am trying to install rbenv. I tried  `rbenv install 3.2.0` but I received:

```
BUILD FAILED (Mac OS X 10.15.7 using ruby-build 20230202)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/yk/clm8vmf15r9cv4hghy2wm6380000gn/T/ruby-build.20230204101926.59465.X5ikLb
Results logged to /var/folders/yk/clm8vmf15r9cv4hghy2wm6380000gn/T/ruby-build.20230204101926.59465.log

Last 10 log lines:
  "_strdup", referenced from:
      _OSSL_provider_init in p_test-dso-p_test.o
  "_strlen", referenced from:
      _p_get_params in p_test-dso-p_test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang  -Iinclude  -arch x86_64 -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe  -D_REENTRANT -DOPENSSL_BUILDING_OPENSSL -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -I/Users/shirinvafaei/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -MMD -MF test/buildtest_c_blowfish-bin-buildtest_blowfish.d.tmp -MT test/buildtest_c_blowfish-bin-buildtest_blowfish.o -c -o test/buildtest_c_blowfish-bin-buildtest_blowfish.o test/buildtest_blowfish.c
make[1]: *** [test/p_test.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [build_sw] Error 2
```

What is wrong that should be solved?

Update:

I tried the following codes from `https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1505`

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
$ xcode-select --install
$ sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

And then `rbenv install 3.2.0`
I received:

```
To follow progress, use 'tail -f /var/folders/yk/clm8vmf15r9cv4hghy2wm6380000gn/T/ruby-build.20230204103403.1653.log' or pass --verbose
Downloading openssl-1.1.1s.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/c5ac01e760ee6ff0dab61d6b2bbd30146724d063eb322180c6f18a6f74e4b6aa
Installing openssl-1.1.1s...

BUILD FAILED (Mac OS X 10.15.7 using ruby-build 20230202)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/yk/clm8vmf15r9cv4hghy2wm6380000gn/T/ruby-build.20230204103403.1653.L02zPW
Results logged to /var/folders/yk/clm8vmf15r9cv4hghy2wm6380000gn/T/ruby-build.20230204103403.1653.log

Last 10 log lines:
      _dgram_write in bss_dgram.o
      _fd_write in bss_fd.o
      _fd_puts in bss_fd.o
      _sock_write in bss_sock.o
      _sock_puts in bss_sock.o
     (maybe you meant: _UI_method_get_writer, _RAND_write_file , _PEM_write_bio_PKCS7_stream , _PEM_write_X509_AUX , _PEM_write_PrivateKey , _PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey_traditional , _PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey , _PEM_write_PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO , _PEM_write_bio_PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO , _PEM_write_PKCS8PrivateKey , _PEM_write_bio_PKCS8PrivateKey , _PEM_write_bio , _PEM_X509_INFO_write_bio , _PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY , _PEM_write_DHparams , _PEM_write_EC_PUBKEY , _PEM_write_bio_EC_PUBKEY , _PEM_write_bio_ECPKParameters , _PEM_write_DSA_PUBKEY , _PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY , _PEM_write_RSAPublicKey , _PEM_write_PKCS7 , _PEM_write_bio_PKCS7 , _PEM_write_X509_CRL , _PEM_write_bio_X509_REQ_NEW , _PEM_write_X509_REQ , _PEM_write_bio_X509 , _PEM_write_PKCS8 , _PEM_write_DHxparams , _PEM_write_DSAparams , _PEM_write_ECPKParameters , _PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey , _UI_method_set_writer , _PEM_write_bio_X509_AUX , _PEM_write_ECPrivateKey , _SMIME_write_CMS , _PEM_write_DSAPrivateKey , _PEM_write_X509 , _PEM_write , _PEM_write_bio_DSAPrivateKey , _PEM_write_bio_X509_CRL , _PEM_write_bio_NETSCAPE_CERT_SEQUENCE , _SMIME_write_PKCS7 , _PEM_ASN1_write , _PEM_ASN1_write_bio , _PEM_write_bio_CMS , _CRYPTO_THREAD_write_lock , _PEM_write_bio_DHxparams , _PEM_write_bio_DSAparams , _PEM_write_RSA_PUBKEY , _TXT_DB_write , _PEM_write_PUBKEY , _BIO_meth_set_write_ex , _BIO_meth_set_write , _BIO_meth_get_write , _PEM_write_bio_DSA_PUBKEY , _BIO_write_ex , _PEM_write_bio_X509_REQ , _PEM_write_bio_Parameters , _PEM_write_bio_ECPrivateKey , _PEM_write_bio_PKCS8 , _PEM_write_X509_REQ_NEW , _PEM_write_bio_DHparams , _BIO_ctrl_get_write_guarantee , _BIO_meth_get_write_ex , _PEM_write_bio_PKCS8PrivateKey_nid , _PEM_write_bio_ASN1_stream , _PEM_write_bio_CMS_stream , _BIO_write , _PEM_write_CMS , _PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey , _PEM_write_NETSCAPE_CERT_SEQUENCE , _PEM_write_PKCS8PrivateKey_nid , _SMIME_write_ASN1 , _PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [libcrypto.dylib] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: My preprocessor is 1.7 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7

Answer (score 0):

`rbenv install xx` installs a ruby version with `rbenv`. To install rbenv use [brew](https://brew.sh/), e.g.

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build
```

`brew` also installs any required dependencies for you.